# how to display data from a database in a table format in a form in access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office, ms-access-2007

I am creating an application in MS-ACCESS 2007 in which I have created a table which holds personal information of students and similarly a form which accepts data from the user and on the click of submit button, inserts the data in the table. Now I want to display 14 out of those 18 columns of my table on the form(in the table like format) when the user clicks on display button.
I got some videos on displaying data using DataGridView but I could not find this widget.
Is there any other method to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Open the form in design view. Go to Properties, Format, Default View and select DataSheetView for display.

Comment: I want the table to be displayed on my form on the click of a button. DataSheetView does not let me do this.

Comment: It does. Set its `RecordSource` to: `Select * From tblYourTable`.